# Delete function IRestResponse with RestSharp

Tags: asp.net, api, restsharp

I want to implement a delete function with a Restful API with RestSharp. I have implemended GET and POST function already. But with this delete function I don't get any feedback from the API only a httpresponse. My question is how do I make my code so I can excecute the delete function? I already have this:

```
//    var url = string.Format("url");

//    Construct the request.
//    var request = new RestRequest(url, Method.DELETE);

//    //IRestResponse<> response;
//    //response = await restClient.ExecuteTaskAsync<>(request);
//    //return response.Data;
```

Comment: Isn't the returned status code the only feedback you're supposed to get? 200 OK is usually success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try it

```
var client = new RestClient(url);
var request = new RestRequest(Method.DELETE);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

The important point here is to include "Accept" in header with value shown in code.

```
        string url = "http://localhost:8080/laptop-bag/webapi/api/delete/2";

        IRestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest(url);
        restRequest.AddHeader("Accept", "*/*"); //Important

        IRestClient restClient = new RestClient();
        IRestResponse restResponse = restClient.Delete(restRequest);
        
        //Status code will be 200 for successful execution
        int statusCode = Convert.ToInt32(restResponse.StatusCode);
```